# OSX pkgbuild: Place package's plist in startup disk when installing to alternate volume

Tags: macos, installation, pkgbuild

We're creating the installer for an Audio Plugin using pkgbuild. It consists of several packages (VST, AU, Content, Presets etc.).

Since the content is quite big we want to allow users to install the content package to external drives. I got that working with the appropriate settings in the distribution.xml (customLocationAllowAlternateVolumes="Yes"). However when the content is installed to such an external drive, the installer also places a .plist and a .bom file on the external drive in /Library/Receipts folder (which it creates) on that drive (see screenshot).

This folder structure is created on the external drive:

[image: This is created on the external drive]

**How can I achieve that these files are placed onto the startup disk no matter to which drive the content package is installed?**

Here is the pkgbuild script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Name of the package.
NAME="<OurProductName> Content"

IDENTIFIER="com.<OurCompanyName>.content.pkg.<OurProductName>"

# Package version number. The correct number will be set in the build process.
VERSION="1.0.1"

INSTALL_LOCATION="/Library/Application Support/<OurCompanyName>/<OurProductName>"
ROOT_LOCATION="content/"

# Remove any unwanted .DS_Store files.
find "$ROOT_LOCATION" -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete
chmod -R +r "$ROOT_LOCATION"

# Build package.
/usr/bin/pkgbuild \
    --root "$ROOT_LOCATION" \
    --install-location "$INSTALL_LOCATION" \
    --identifier "$IDENTIFIER" \
    --version "$VERSION" \
    --scripts Scripts \
    "$NAME.pkg"
```

This is the relevant snippet from the distribution file:

```
<pkg-ref id="com.<OurCompanyName>.content.pkg.<OurProductName>" version="1.0.1" auth="Admin" onConclusion="None">Some%20Product%20Name%20Content.pkg</pkg-ref>
<choice id="Content" title="<OurProductName> Content" start_visible="true" start_selected="true" start_enabled="true" customLocation="/Library/Application Support/<OurCompanyName>/<OurProductName>" customLocationAllowAlternateVolumes="Yes" description='You can change the file location for the plugin content file. Click on the folder name in "Location" to select a different one.'>
    <pkg-ref id="com.<OurCompanyName>.content.pkg.<OurProductName>"/>
</choice>
```